# Is "increment" perfectly synonymous with "increase"?

Tags: synonyms, ambiguity

My advisor replaced all the occurrences of "increment" with "increase" in one of my papers. Is it true that "increment" can always be replaced with "increase"? If not, please show me some examples.

Comment: Show us your background research effort.

Comment: People will always ask about "perfect synonyms". And we always have to tell them, there is no such thing. Synonyms only exist *in context*. Antonyms only exist *in context*. Hypernyms only exist *in context*. For the simple reason that all these -nyms are about *meaning*, and words only have meaning *in context*. Without context, a word as simple as *cat* can mean a dozen things; it is not even synonymous with itself. Likewise, *man* can be the antonym of *woman*, or the antonym of *boy*, or the antonym of *God*, or the antonym of *animal* — even though a man *is* an animal and not a plant.

Comment: @RegDwighт: You are such a cool cat. Those are great examples, showing why this question sorely needs at least one or two excerpts from the paper in question. (Incidentally, _man_ can function as an antonym of _woman_, as you said, or as a hypernym of _woman_ as well.)

Comment: This is not a real question until it is edited to include the OP's efforts at research.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, *increase* cannot always replace *increment*. In mathematics, increment [can refer to a *decrease*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/increments).

An increase, on the other hand, always refers to [the act, amount or rate of getting larger](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/increase).

That said, in ***common usage***, an increment is an increase, generally with the specific connotation of being:

> [*one of a series of regular additions or contributions*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/increments)

Consider the following sentence:

> John added to his savings account in increments.

Here **increment** expresses something that **increase** by itself does not. It would generally be understood as:

> John added to his savings in a series of identical amounts.

In common usage, then, increase has a broader meaning than increment. Depending on the context, increment may be a more accurate word than increase - or it may be misleading.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to write.

> Increment is the unit of measure or the process of increasing

Sometimes there is no difference and they are interchangeable, but 'increment' indicates an increase in regular steps, whereas 'increase' has a wider, more general usage.

This means that sometimes only 'increase' is the correct word to use.

Answer (score 2):

> My advisor replaced all the occurrences of "increment" with "increase" in one of my papers. Is it true that "increment" can always be replaced with "increase"?

No, *increment* cannot "always" be replaced with *increase*. However, that doesn't mean that your advisor was wrong: *increase* is a more "generic" word, and it may indeed have been the more appropriate word in the usages in your paper.

Unfortunately, you haven't taken the time to provide even a single example from your paper, so there's no way for us to tell if these replacements represent improvements.  We don't even know if you are talking about a noun or verb usage of these words.

In short, *increase* can be used as a verb, meaning *to go up*. The word *increase* can also be used as a noun, meaning *a single instance of making a value higher*.  So, I could say either of these:

> *Betty, we are going to **increase** your pay*.  (used as a verb)
>   *Netty, you are going to receive a pay **increase***. (used as a noun)

But the word *increment* would not be appropriate in either of those sentences.  The word *increment* implies one of a series:

> *Eddy, we are going to **increase** your salary $2000 per year for the next three years. Each **increment** will take effect on January 1st.*

Comment: @RegDwigнt But what about the words "yeah" and "yes"? These words have exactly the same meaning, and I can't find any context in which the meaning would differ. If you answer any question with both, the meaning will always be the same, yes.

Comment: Both words can be used to answer a question in the affirmative, but one is more informal that the other, so I wouldn't say they are entirely interchangeable in all contexts. Plus, there is the famous ["Yeah, right" joke](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/humor/double-positive.html), which wouldn't exactly work with, "Yes, correct."

Comment: No, you wouldn't use these two words in all SOCIAL contexts, but this is not important linguistically. What's important is that these two words have the exact same meaning in all of the contexts(Even in your 'Yeah, right' example 'yeah' alone means 'yes').  They both mean "yes" and this is what I was trying to prove when I've heard the statement that there are no perfect synonyms.